# IOS 7 Default Sharing Dialog, Message getting strange design behavior

Tags: iphone, ios7, share, message

In iOS 7 Default sharing Dialog, Message is getting strange design behavior. I have open Message, on To textfield i typed some letters, after i pressed backspace button in keyboard. At last the design gets strange behavior.

Can any one help me. How to resolve this?